# Ubuntu boot problem, new nvidia install

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia-geforce

Yesterday I tried to connect my laptop with a 4k monitor. After looking around online I found it was recommended to purge bumblebee and the nvidia driver and to reinstall the nvidia driver. Unfortunately upon booting i now get the following screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNrL9.jpg

I have ubuntu 16.04 and an Nvidia gtx 1060 mq video card whilst i have probably mistakenly installed 1080 driver software

To be clear I am unable to access the terminal so I am unaware of a way to reinstall a different driver. I have tried going to boot in recovery mode. The recovery boot commands are as follows: path, root, ro recovery nomodeset acpi_osi=Linux-Dell-Video

I have tried to edit this line but to no avail yet. The system has Grub version 2 installed. Unlike the normal boot, recovery boot does not display any failed systems. The problem is that the screen blinks. (Splitsecond on, 10 seconds off) and the input from the keyboard is also only available during that split second. I have not been able to input my login and password due to this. Are there boot arguments that i should use? Is there a way to install a different nividia software?

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the Fast Boot (if exist) and Secured Boot (if exist) in BIOS to have more time to get to `grub2` menu.

In `grub2` menu select Advanced options, select Recovery Mode. Activate network and select `root`. press `enter`. welcome to root terminal in recovery with online access.

Regarding the drivers,I had same issues on Ubuntu 18.04 and Mint 19.1 with Lenovo Y530 and nvidia 1050 GTX graphic card. I hope this will help you. I must say I haven't managed to fix the HDMI Port issue yet but at least you could use your laptop again.

clean all nvidia stuff(don't forget the star):
`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

add this ppa repo :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

this will print a list of your available drivers from apt. one of the has a recommended tag at the end.
mine is `nvidia-driver-418`.
now run
`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418 nvidia-prime` of course with the recommended version to you.

now to make sure it works:

```
prime-select query // probably the output will be 'nvidia'
sudo prime select intel
prime-select query // should print 'intel' 
reboot
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately the recovery mode boot fails before I can select root. I made a short vid with my phone of what happens: https://youtu.be/xHqb1-d4iqY         The end result is basically just asking my login and password. I also changed lightdm to gdm btw, dont know if its relevant. I think I need to change the parameters of the recovery boot but I do not know what I need to change.

Comment: I'm not sure how you should proceed here. try to search in your BIOS if there's an option to disable nvidia graphics. maybe you'll gain access to your pc with the Intel graphics. if this doesn't work i would consider using CD/USB ubuntu boot and try to reinstall with keeping your personal data.